# Accessing Python functions from a large Git repository in R

Tags: r, reticulate

My company has a large Git repository that is actively being developed (call it `really-big-repo`). I would like to use the `reticulate` package to call some of those python functions in R. Apologies in advance as I still try to get my arms around both python and git.

Single python files can be called using `reticulate::source_python("flights.py")` (see [here](https://git+git://github.com:strider-technologies/ribs-ui.git@master)). However, the python script I would like to imports modules that are from other parts of the repository. For example, the file that I would like to source `great_python_functions.py` looks like this:

```
import datetime
import json
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from SomeRepoDirectory import utils
from SomeRepoDirectory.entity.models import Entity, EntityAlias, EntityBase, Subsidiary
import SomeRepoDirectory.entity.wikipedia
from SomeRepoDirectory.io.es import es_h
...
```

To further complicate it, the repo is pretty large and this file is just a small part of it. I'm not sure it is wise to load ALL of the repo's functions into my R environment.

And one more bonus question. I really would like to access the functions that are on a branch of the repo, not master. I've cloned the repository to a different directory than my R project using `git clone git@github.com:my-company-name/really-big-repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following steps you can try, but gotta say this is going to be complicated, might I say learning python might be easier :p

Like you said you have cloned the repository:

```
cd ./cloned_repo
conda activate your_vitual_env
git checkout feature/branch
python setup.py develop # this will install the pkg in virtual env, you can also use install instead of develop
```

Now in your R, use the virtual env in which you installed the repo, in my example I am using `conda` env, so you can use: `reticulate::use_condaenv('your_virtual_env')` and then you should be able to use those functions.

Also, in my experience intermingling `python` and `R` has caused a lot of pain for production development especially with package management. So I will advise some caution.

Comment: The mingling of R and Python is RStudio's recent push and I think part of the reason they developed the `reticulate` package. https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/r-python-a-data-science-love-story/

Comment: my intention was not to impose my opinion, but was trying to share my experience. For personal development, I do too use R and Python and I like that flexibility, but managing two different languages and their dependencies in production was difficult for us.